# Tool to count the miss rate of assembly

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to speed up the execution of my code cpp and thought of looking at cache misses maybe I could change locality. So is there any such a tool? that would tell me the miss rate of every insns in assembly

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel has such tools (VTune).  valgrind is a free alternative.  I seem to remember that IBM in the purify tools suite has also something for that.

Comment: Does valgrind provide the data cache misses? if yes how can invoke it to collect the data?  Thanks:)

Comment: Valgrind is a suite of tools as well as the name of one of the tool in the suite.  Look for cachegrind for the cache simulation tool in the valgrind suite.

Answer (score 1):

- Intel VTune (Windows & Linux)
- AMD CodeAnalyst (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: If you have a particular system that you are targeting, it is possible that there might exist a simulator which will do this type of thing, but I think you would find in practice that the caching mechanisms vary so greatly from system to system that it would be very difficult to get a meaningful statistic.